# Unable to pass "this" pointer to another class and calling any methods of that class in CPP

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, interface

Here I am trying to pass the instance of ATMMachine using "this" keyword to the HasCard class and trying to call any method of ATMMachine from HasClass using that instance. But I am not able to call any of the methods of ATMMachine. 
For example unable to call `machine->insertCard();`
Could someone please help me to find out where the problem is? 
Is there any better approach in CPP to communicate between classes?

```
class ATMState{
    virtual void insertCard() = 0;
    virtual void ejectCard() = 0;
    virtual void insertPin(int pinNumber) = 0;
    virtual void withdrawCash(int amount) = 0;
};

class ATMMachine;

class HasCard: public ATMState {
private:
    ATMMachine* machine;
public:
    HasCard(ATMMachine* _machine) {
        machine = _machine;
        machine->insertCard();
    }
    void insertCard() {

    }

    void ejectCard() {

    }

    void insertPin(int pinNumber) {

    }

    void withdrawCash(int amount) {

    }
};

class ATMMachine{
    public:
    int balance;
    ATMState* currentState;
    ATMState* hasCard;
    ATMState* noCard;
    ATMState* hasPin;
    ATMState* noCash;

    ATMMachine() {
        hasCard =  new HasCard(this);
//        noCard =  new NoCard();
//        noCash =  new NoCash();
//        hasPin =  new HasPin();
        currentState = hasCard;
    }

    void insertCard() {
        cout<<"Card has been inserted" <<endl;
    }

    void ejectCard() {

    }

    void insertPin(int pinNumber) {

    }

    void withdrawCash(int amount) {

    }
};
```

Comment: can you show the main function?

Comment: Does not compile.  Missing `#include` directives.  `ATMMachine` is an incomplete type.

Comment: This is just an ordering issue. You are trying to use `ATMMachine` before it has been fully defined. You need to move around your classes and function definitions so that this is not the case any more. Hard to give specific advice because it looks like there's a lot of code missing from what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`But I am not able to call any of the methods of ATMMachine.` with the forward declaration `class ATMMachine;` you only tell that this class exists, but the compiler does not know anything of its member functions until the full class definition is reached.

That's why you get an error like this:

> ```
>    invalid use of incomplete type 'class ATMMachine'
>        machine->insertCard();
>    note: forward declaration of 'class ATMMachine'
>        class ATMMachine;
> ```

If you have this kind of cross dependencies you need to split the declaration of the member functions, constructors, or destructors and their definitions.

```
class ATMState {
  virtual void insertCard() = 0;
  virtual void ejectCard() = 0;
  virtual void insertPin(int pinNumber) = 0;
  virtual void withdrawCash(int amount) = 0;
};

class ATMMachine;

class HasCard : public ATMState {
private:
  ATMMachine *machine;

public:
  // only declare the constructor here
  HasCard(ATMMachine *_machine);

  void insertCard() {}

  void ejectCard() {}

  void insertPin(int pinNumber) {}

  void withdrawCash(int amount) {}
};

class ATMMachine {
public:
  int balance;
  ATMState *currentState;
  ATMState *hasCard;
  ATMState *noCard;
  ATMState *hasPin;
  ATMState *noCash;

  ATMMachine() {
    hasCard = new HasCard(this);
    //        noCard =  new NoCard();
    //        noCash =  new NoCash();
    //        hasPin =  new HasPin();
    currentState = hasCard;
  }

  void insertCard() { cout << "Card has been inserted" << endl; }

  void ejectCard() {}

  void insertPin(int pinNumber) {}

  void withdrawCash(int amount) {}
};

// move the definition of the HasCard constructor after the declaration of ATMMachine
HasCard::HasCard(ATMMachine *_machine){
    machine = _machine;
    machine->insertCard();
}
```

`Is there any better approach in CPP to communicate between classes?` Having the need to do something like that is often an indication that you should restructure your code. There are various ways how to solve such issues each with their pros and cons. But that's something to ask on codereview.